# Unable to clear doctrine 2 collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, associations

I have a oneToMany association between two entities, Campsite and WeatherForecast.
Before adding new forecasts to a campsite I want to clear all existing. I try the following, but no delete queries are executed whatsoever. Anyone can shed a light on this?

```
$campsite = $campsiteRepository->find('campsite-2013-100006');

echo $campsite->getForecasts()->count() . PHP_EOL; //Outputs 7

$campsite->getForecasts()->clear();

echo $campsite->getForecasts()->count(); //Outputs 0

$em->persist($campsite);
$em->flush();
```

**Campsite entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AcsiCampsiteWeather\Entity\Forecast", mappedBy="campsite")
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $forecasts
 */
protected $forecasts = null;
```

**Forecast entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AcsiCampsite\Entity\Campsite", inversedBy="forecasts", fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="relationID", referencedColumnName="relationID", nullable=false)
 * @var \AcsiCampsite\Entity\Campsite $campsite
 */
protected $campsite = null;
```

Comment: Could you please show your mapping config for both entities?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post tomorrow when I'm at work

Comment: @Exander, I've added the related annotations

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is correct, because, [according to the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html), the oneToMany side of an association is always the inverse side, and changes made to it will not be persisted. You need to apply the changes to the owning side. But don't forget to change the inverse side, too, if you want your object graph to stay consistent (if you're planning on working with the forecasts' collection later in the code). So, in the end, I suppose the code should look something like this:

```
$campsite = $campsiteRepository->find('campsite-2013-100006');
foreach($campsite->getForecasts() as $forecast) {
    $em->remove($forecast);
}

$campsite->getForecasts()->clear();

// your entities should already be tracked by the Unit of Work, so you shoudn't need to do this
// $em->persist($campsite);
$em->flush();
```

I suppose you can also specify [orphanRemoval=true](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) in the annotaion for your oneToMany association (as far as I've understood, each forecast is always tied to one campsite once, then deleted). Although somehow I've never done this, as I prefer being explicit.

Also see [this page of the reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) for info about working with associations.